# Is it possible to track the data collected by iPhone apps in your device with relevant server names they are sent to?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile

I want to develop an iPhone application which can track the contents (such as location information, device hardware/sw information, contacts …etc)  being collected from your device by all the applications and give a report to the end user at end of each week.

Because, I believe that end user should be notified about what information being collected by his device and sent to which servers to store them. 
I Googled it and read few articles as well, but all pointed to the conclusion that a given application cannot (or restricted by Apple) peak into operations of other apps and collect any information about what those applications are doing. 
But I've seen this Onovo Count app http://www.onavo.com/apps/iphone_count is collecting the data usage of all the other apps in your device, so can we just go few steps beyond that get this done ?

Comment: This is impossible using public APIs on a non-jailbroken device.

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks for the comment, yes this is the first (and only) answer I got over and over again from others when I raised the same question. I need something out of the box answer. Can you think of a way how the Onovo Count collects memory usage information ?

Comment: Onovo data usage screen shots are misleading, have you actually downloaded the app and run several (non built in) apps making network connections then see what Onova actually can report? Do it rather than looking at their nice screen shots, you might be disappointed.

Comment: Yes I did, and the numbers they display on app are much deviated from the actual. So yes, there should be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it Onovo Count redirects all device traffic through a VPN. I presume their servers look at the host names of the traffic and record it against the device. When looking at the app, you're just looking at a dump of the data for your device.

For the rest of what you want to do, it is not possible on a standard device, you'd need to have it jail broken or something.

Comment: lets assume I have an application dealing with a server through HTTPS (through a SSL tunnel), how can someone look at my traffic without breaking SSL encryptions ? I think their memory calculation algorithm has a way of looking at more system level properties.

Comment: Yes, but only the host name of the request, not the body or path/query.

Comment: still I don't get how they can redirect all my device traffic into a VPN. Because if I write an application. I will just hard code the server URL value inside my codes, so how can they interfere that ?

Comment: Have you tried to download and run that application (granted I haven't!) but they'll need to you connect to a VPN when the app starts. You can see that from the `VPN` icon in the status bar (and also from reading the reviews of the app).

Comment: Yes, I see what you meant. They force you to use their VPN tunnel.